# Expand / Collapse all hierarchy in Outliner

Tags: objects, armature, outliner

How do I twirl down everything in a hierarchy in the Outliner? For example, on armatures it's sometimes tiresome having to click on the twirl down-arrow on every single bone if you want an overview of the armature in the Outliner. Is there a quicker way to do this?

[image]

Starting point.

[image]

This is what I would like to achieve without having to manually click on the twirl down-arrow on every single bone.

*Please note: This is just an example armature and maybe not the best example. Sometimes there's armatures with over 100 bones, and I'm more specially talking about those cases where it actually gets very tiresome twirling down everything.*

Comment: Or you can just press **shift+A** :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Simply click on expand arrow with <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> key.

It will expand/collapse everything under it. So if you need to

- Expand all (under collection) - click on Collection
- Expand only specific bone chain - click on Armature

Example with and without <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> key:

[image]

Or use "+" / "-" key (with cursor in *Outliner* Editor) to open / close one level.

More details in [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/outliner.html#view-menu).

Answer (score 0):

Also, <kbd>Home</kbd> key expands everything.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.